create stored procedure in that one row is data is there it will show error and data is not there it will ecexute
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ifconditionerror(
    IN  emplyee_id INT, 
    IN employee_name VARCHAR(200),
    FLAG TINYINT)
BEGIN
     IF FLAG = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (id, name)  
        VALUES (emplyee_id , employee_name);  
    ELSE
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Data already exists';  
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

I want mysql query  in this one row data is there it will show error and in that there is no data that row will executed  i want like that data in mysql  Answer

"it will show error" - can you share that error, along with your attempts to resolve the problem? As this is tagged specifically with [tag:mysql-workbench]: the error is not occuring when using any other tool?
